# BQ INFORMATION_SCHEMA Data retention 180 Days

Tags: google-bigquery, information-schema

Is there a way to increase INFORMATION_SCHEMA default Data Retention past 180 Days?

I have a requirement to report on User Query Trends for a large amount of time, greater than 180 days.

Any and all feedback and comments are welcome :)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think it is possible to increase data retention beyond 180 days at the moment. You will have to copy the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to your BQ and store the schema view by yourself.

Comment: I'm wondering if the data you seek is already (or can be) sent to Google Cloud Logging?  While the INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides an already present table you can query, it might be that the data is also sent to Cloud Logging.  If yes, then you can direct that Cloud Logging to either an additional BQ table or a GCS file.  Alternatively, as Nestor suggested, run a scheduled job to append to a separate table the records added to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA since last your appended.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I'll go with creating my own schema and parking the Historic data there.